# ¿Se puede crear un hipervinculo en tkinter que una frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formularios, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en python .Quiero hacer un formulario dividido varias partes y que cada una tenga dos botones "atras" y "siguiente" para ir recorriendo todo el formulario.
Busque por muchas paginas pero no encuentro info sobre como hacer esto.

Comment: ¿Qué código tienes? Considera añadir lo que hayas intentado para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a su pregunta primero que todo la pregunta está muy generalizada, cuando está haciendo referencia a "frames", según su criterio que es lo que está intentando hacer, porque está muy generalizado. También debe mostrar su avance o su código para evidenciar las posibles soluciones o errores. En mi opinión una de las soluciones más viables para su pregunta es la siguiente como lo menciona si quiere usar un hipervínculo o label que ejecute una acción:

Ejemplo #1: Especifique el widget o label, en mi caso sería lo siguiente

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk() 
root.geometry('900x650')
root.title('Ejemplos')

def EjecutarEvento(event=None): #Event, el argumento se debe poner para ejecutar la 
                                #acción, "None", para evitar agregar el argumento
                                #event en cada widget o label.
    print('Esto debe suceder cuando se hace clic en el label')

labelEjemplo = tk.Label(root, text="Esto es un label", font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, 
"underline"), foreground="DodgerBlue3")
labelEjemplo.place(x=10, y=50)
labelEjemplo.bind("<Button-1>", EjecutarEvento)

root.mainloop()
```

Ejemplo #2 : Frame o un label expandido con evento

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk() 
root.geometry('900x650')
root.title('Ejemplos')

def EjecutarEvento(event=None): #Event, el argumento se debe poner para ejecutar la 
                                #acción, "None", para evitar agregar el argumento
                                #event en cada widget o label.
    print('Esto debe suceder cuando se hace clic en el label')

OpenFileLabel = tk.Label(root, width=107, height=10, borderwidth=1, relief='sunken', 
text='Haga clic aquí para ejecutar el evento', font= 
('Microsoft Sans Serif', 9, 'bold'))
OpenFileLabel.place(x=18, y=70)
OpenFileLabel.bind("<1>", EjecutarEvento)

FrameEvent = Frame(root, width=860, height=170, bg='blue') #Frame con evento 
FrameEvent.place(x=18, y=250)
FrameEvent.bind("<1>", EjecutarEvento)


LabelInFrame = tk.Label(FrameEvent, text='Ejemplo de un Frame con evento', font= ('Microsoft Sans Serif', 9, 'bold'), fg='white', bg='blue')
LabelInFrame.place(x=18, y=70) #Label dentro de un Frame con evento
LabelInFrame.bind("<1>", EjecutarEvento)


root.mainloop()
```

> "bind", hace referencia al evento o acción al hacer clic con el cursor (devolución de llamada).

Si lo que está haciendo es usar un label simple para ejecutar un evento
la opción más viable es que use el primer ejemplo. Estos ejemplos son probados y usados
en Python 3.5.3 (64-bit) y usando Tkinter 8.6. Si lo que está intentando hacer es usar botones, use `command` para ejecutar la acción y tomar la referencia de una función o varias a la vez (función anónima). Ejemplo:

```
def EjecutarEventoBoton():
    print('Esto debe suceder cuando se hace clic en el botón')

btnOk = tk.Button(root, text='Boton1', takefocus=False, command=EjecutarEventoBoton)
btnOk.place(x=13,y=78)
```

Para ejecutar varias funciones a la vez solo utilice `lambda` o como se conoce como *función anónima*, como por ejemplo: `command=lambda:[(PrimeraFunción(), SegundaFunción())])`. Esto si usted está adaptando varias operaciones a la vez en un solo botón o en un hoja de propiedades como en los botones *Aceptar, Cancelar o Aplicar*.

Si no entiende le recomiendo que revise la documentación al respecto de [Python](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/index.html) y [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/tk.html) antes que todo. También a [como elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. En lo posible, evita responder a preguntas poco claras y/o de baja calidad. Lee [answer], en especial la sección _Contesta preguntas bien formadas_.